# Rails, oauth vs oauth2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to know the difference between oauth and oauth2 gems available in ruby and which one can be used to connect with various sites like facebook, twitter, salesforce etc (There are many plug-ins available for this but can we create a single APIs for connecting all oauth provider).

~N a R e N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These two gems differ by the version of [OAuth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth) standard they implement, respectively 1 and 2.

The choice depends on the OAuth providers you want to work with and what versions they support. For example, Facebook supports only OAuth 2, but some older systems might support OAuth 1 only.

Comment: Thanks Nikita for your response. 
does this mean that "I've to use both gem to support all oauth providers?" Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: @Naren Usually no. You need to see which providers you want to work with, most likely they support OAuth 2 already. And in any case, there's no way to "support all oauth providers". Supporting one of them implies using provider-specific tokens. You can't send the same "grant me access to user's photos" request to twitter, as you do to facebook. Twitter uses its own set of tokens for its own actions.